# Best way to create a downloader

Tags: c#, ftp, download, launcher, torrent

What's the best way to implement a downloader inside a launcher (for my application)?

I thought about these methods:

- Direct html download
- FTP
- Via torrent

and I was wondering what's the best either frontend and backend (and maybe the most secure).

Thank you

Comment: what kind of application you are talking about ? a Web Application ?

Comment: A small game, but I want my users to have the chance to update it automatically with said launcher.

Comment: So a game ! Are you building it in C# ? A Windows Phone App, Desktop App or Web App ?

Comment: Most modern game updaters use both HTTP and Torrent, being Torrent the default option. The user (or the application) can switch to HTTP when Torrent is not performing for whatever reason (Firewall etc.). Torrent is best when you have multiple update servers serving the data so the user can download from multiple sources at once and speed up updating process.

Comment: FTP is obsolete for this kind of stuff, it has absolutely no advantage over HTTP, in fact it only creates complications.

Comment: @lame_coder: Yes, I'm building it in C# (or at least, I'm trying, it's nothing worth playing lol, I'm just testing), and that's a desktop app.

Comment: @Havenard: I have only one server (1 gbit bandwith), so you recommend HTTP?
And what about security? HTTPS and file encryption?

Comment: HTTPS would be nice. But adding file encryption is unnecessary in most cases.

Comment: @Havenard: Oh, so I'll try with HTTPS! Thanks guys!